# iOS Hide button with equal width constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

So I am trying to implement some feature restrictions based on permissions in an app. The feature in question works on a button that is placed at the bottom of the VC in main.storyboard.

There is another button that I want to remain there. They are aligned horizontally, but not in a horizontal stack view. They have an equal-width constraint and together take up the whole vertical space at the bottom.

I want to hide the first one, and thus have the second one take up that entire horizontal space from left to right, but only when the access to the first button is supposed to be restricted. I've tried doing this in viewNeedsRefresh:

```
let equalWidthConstraint = firstButton.superview?.constraints.filter{
                $0.firstItem as? UIButton == firstButton && $0.secondItem as? UIButton == secondButton
            }.first
equalWidthConstraint?.isActive = false
firstButton.isHidden = true
secondButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: firstButton.frame.origin.y, width: self.view.frame.width, height: firstButton.frame.height)
```

But all this does is hide the first button, while the second button is suddenly partially off-screen. If I try without manually disabling the constraint, I get it looking cleaner but the second button is still in its original position, likely because it still maintains the original width due to the constraint.

Comment: Why not create buttons programmatically?

Comment: It's for work, and that portion of the project was done long ago. I'm trying to keep changes minor, and modifying the storyboard that much will take longer to get the new changes approved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out they built a re-usable component for this in the past before I joined, but did not actually use it more than once. I have converted the page to use that component instead. Sorry guys.

Comment: Can you delete this question or mark a correct answer?

Comment: You marked this answer as correct, but this answer failed to answer the actual question.

Comment: Not useful answer as per the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, in my opinion, I'd do the following:

1. remove the equal widths constraint
2. set a width constraint on one of the buttons set to 0.5x the superview width, then create an outlet for the constraint
3. set the other button with a trailing or leading (depending on the button you chose) to zero.
4. When you need to collapse the button, you can now set the constraint's constant directly like so:

   ```
   buttonWidth.constant = 0
   ```

That would hide the view and give you the desired effect.